# Add content-type header while consuming API using GraphQL.client

Tags: c#, graphql

I am using GraphQL.client Nuget package to call the Graphql API which requires Content-Type header.
Following is what I am doing

Set GraphQL options. Note I have set options.MediaType

```
GraphQLHttpClientOptions options = new GraphQLHttpClientOptions();
options.MediaType = "application/json";
options.EndPoint = new Uri( "https://sample.api.com/graphql");
```

Initialize the client and Authorization header

```
var graphQLClient = new GraphQLHttpClient(options, new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer());         
graphQLClient.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "JWT <token>");
```

GraphQL query

```
var projectsQuery = new GraphQLRequest
{
  Query = @"
    query {
      projects {
        name
      }
    }"
};
```

Invoke the API and retrieve the response results

```
var graphQLResponse = await graphQLClient.SendQueryAsync<ProjectResponse>(projectsQuery);            
var projects = graphQLResponse.Data.Projects;
```

However I am getting Bad request with error `"{"errors":[{"message":"Must provide query string."}]}"`

What am I doing wrong here? How do I set the content-type header correctly. I tried adding the content-type header as below but it does not allow giving the

> Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with
> HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and
> content headers with HttpContent objects.

```
graphQLClient.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("content-type", "application/json");
```

I tried searching for a solution but did not find one. The same request works when I pass content-type header in the request headers via Postman client.

Does anybody have any pointer on the same?

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is still looking for answer, please find below.

```
var graphQLClient = new graphQLHttpClient("https://www.example.com/graphql", new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer());
graphQLClient.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("key", "value");
```

Please mind the **HttpClient** in graphQLClient.**HttpClient**.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("key", "value");